# How to know if all the setState updates have been applied to the state in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, state

I was reading the documentation about React [setState](https://devdocs.io/react/react-component#setstate), which says:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

Now I have a component like this:

```
class NoteScreenComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { note: Note.newNote() }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ note: this.props.note });
    }

    noteComponent_change = (propName, propValue) => {
        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            let note = Object.assign({}, prevState.note);
            note[propName] = propValue;
            return { note: note }
        });
    }

    title_changeText = (text) => {
        this.noteComponent_change('title', text);
    }

    body_changeText = (text) => {
        this.noteComponent_change('body', text);
    }

    saveNoteButton_press = () => {
        // Save note to SQL database
        Note.save(this.state.note)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput value={this.state.note.title} onChangeText={this.title_changeText} />
                <TextInput value={this.state.note.body}  onChangeText={this.body_changeText} />
                <Button title="Save note" onPress={this.saveNoteButton_press} />
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

What I'm wondering is, since `setState` does not update the `state` immediately, how can I know if the note I'm saving in `saveNoteButton_press` is the current version of the state? Is there some callback or something that I could poll to know if `state` has been fully updated?

Comment: how about `render()` as the callback that tells you state is done updating?  We know it's ready then, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they are warning against is trying to do something in the same event loop.

```
method = () => {
  this.setState({ note: 'A' })
  saveNote(this.state.note) // <-- this.state.note will not have been updated yet.
}
```

or to `setState` using previous state:

```
method = () => {
  let note = this.state.note // possible that `this.state.note` is scheduled to change
  this.setState({ note: note + 'B' })
}
```

Since your user is going to be pushing the button after the setState scheduling, the state will have already been updated.

..but for theory's sake, let's imagine that somehow the input event and button happen in the exact same moment.. what would be the correct solution? If it was a single function call you probably wouldn't be using the new state since you already have the new note and the previous state.

```
method = (text) => {
  let noteToSave = this.state.note + text // old state + new value

  saveNote(noteToSave) // maybe this will fail
    .then(response => this.setState({ note: noteToSave }))
    .catch(err => this.setState({ error: 'something went wrong' }))

  // optimistically update the ui
  this.setState({ note: noteToSave }) 
}
```

but probably the most likely solution is to just pass what you want as an argument where you use it, rather than trying to access state which *might* be in a race condition, since `render` will happen after any state transitions.

```
method = (note) => {
  noteToSave(note)
}

render() {
  return (
    <Button onPress={() => this.method(this.state.note)} /> <-- must be up to date here
  )
}
```